# Is there an API to configure settings in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm attempting to write an app which diagnosis a variety of issues on your mobile device. Part of this requires me to toggle settings on an IPhone. These are IPhone settings, not my own app settings, or the settings of another application, but the actual IPhone settings on the user's device. Is there an API for this? I cannot seem to find it anywhere if there is.

Comment: I hope not. An app that could reach into my iPhone and change its settings would be Evil.

Comment: Even with your permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no.

Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to change global device settings. Apps are confined to a "sandbox" where they can only affect themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For many settings, it is possible to show an alert advising the user what to do, and then direct them to the right point in "Settings" to make a change as easily as possible.

As matt says, if an app were able to change global settings on my phone, that would be absolutely evil. An incredible security risk.